# Send a xml file from windows to ubuntu

Tags: c#

Visual Studio 2008

I have a xml file I want to send to a ubuntu server.

Before I was using the following to save on the current machine in the application folder. However, the customer has changed and now wants to store it on a remote network ubuntu server.

```
dt.WriteXml(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Config.xml"));
```

What is the best way to send files across the network? Is it possible to send files from a windows machine to a ubuntu server machine?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to use a samba daemon and plain old file copying. If your customer wants to use the Ubuntu server as a file server, they may have already set this up.

Another option is to run an FTP daemon on the server  and use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx) class to upload the file to it. You can use the [WebClient.UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx) method to upload a file to the server or [WebClient.UploadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y.aspx) to upload the string directly, using the FTP STOR command.

Comment: Plain FTP is not as secure as SMB and certainly not as secure as SCP. I'd only do that as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is probably to [SCP](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx) it onto the remote machine.

Comment: Windows boxes come with scp? Never would have guessed.

Comment: After taking a quick look at that link, I still think setting up samba on the ubuntu box is the better option... that way a network share can be mapped and a third party library doesn't get introduced as a dependency; built-in IO can be used instead. But you have way more points than me... what do you think?

Comment: In the end either will work, but it's less effort getting sshd up and running than smbd and nmbd (and to top it off sshd is probably *already* up anyways).

Answer (score 1):

Run a samba daemon on the ubuntu server and you can use shared folders (SMB) to transfer the file.

Comment: You mean you don't have access to the ubuntu server, or what?

Comment: I was thinking of using the webclient to upload the file to the ubuntu server. Yes, I do have access to the server. Thanks.